# Consulta anidada y pivot

Tags: sql-server

Se trata de consultar las administradoras de un empleado, para ello tengo 3 tablas: EMPLEADOS, ADMIN_COTIZANTE, ADMINISTRADORA.

En la tabla ADMINISTRADORA se encuentran registrados todos los proveedores, allí se encuentra un campo TIPO_ADMINISTRADORA (básicamente son 6 tipos: AFP, ARP, CCF, EPS, ICBF, SENA) que se repite según sea la administradora. EJ:

| ADMINISTRADORA | DESCRIPCION | TIPO_ADMINISTRADORA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EPS013 | SALUDCOOP EPS | EPS |
| 230801 | SANTANDER S.A. | AFP |
| CCF44 | CCF DE RISARALDA | CCF |
| 14-28 | SURATEP SA | ARP |
| 14-25 | Colmena ARL | ARP |
| PASENA | SENA | SENA |
| PAICBF | ICBF | ICBF |

La tabla ADMIN_COTIZANTE contiene los campos EMPLEADO, ADMINISTRADORA Y FECHA_INGRESO

| EMPLEADO | ADMINISTRADORA | FECHA_INGRESO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | PASENA | 2012-09-19 |
| 00001 | PAICBF | 2012-09-19 |
| 00001 | EPS013 | 2012-09-19 |
| 00001 | 230801 | 2012-09-19 |
| 00001 | CCF44 | 2012-09-19 |
| 00001 | 14-28 | 2012-09-19 |
| 00001 | 14-25 | 2014-07-01 |

Y en la tabla EMPLEADO se encuentra toda la información básica del empleado, pero no hay ninguna relación entre las 2 anteriores tablas.

Mi problema es obtener cada una de las administradoras (AFP, ARP, CCF, EPS, ICBF, SENA) para cada empleado, ya que como se muestra en la tabla ADMIN_COTIZANTE están las administradoras (14-28 y 14-25) las cuales pertenecen a lo que podríamos llamar "grupo de ARP" y se tiene una fecha de inicio, a lo cual me interesa traer la fecha más reciente.

En conclusión la consulta debería quedar de la siguiente manera

| EMPLEADO | AFP | ARP | CCF | EPS | ICBF | SENA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | SANTANDER S.A. | Colmena ARL | CCF DE RISARALDA | SALUDCOOP EPS | ICBF | SENA |
| 00002 | PROTECCION S.A. | Colmena ARL | CCF COMFAMA | SALUD TOTAL S.A. | ICBF | SENA |
| 00003 | COLPLENSIONES | SURATEP SA | COMFENALCO VALLE | SANITAS S.A. | ICBF | SENA |

Sé que tengo que utilizar un PIVOT para transformar las filas a columnas, pero como 1 empleado puede cambiar de ADMINISTRADORA queda el registro como un historial y me interesa saber en cada grupo de los 6 tipos de administradoras (AFP, ARP, CCF, EPS, ICBF, SENA) cuál es el más reciente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que necesitas hacer, es encontrar la administradora más reciente de cada tipo por cada empleado. Eso lo podemos lograr mediante la función `ROW_NUMBER()`. Puesto que no podemos filtrar directamente del resultado de esa función, necesitamos incluir la consulta en una tabla derivada o una CTE (como pongo en el ejemplo).

Ya teniendo esos valores, solo necesitamos transponer las filas en columnas. Mi método de prefencia es mediante el agregado condicional que funciona bastante bien.

```
WITH cteAdminCotizanteDetalle AS(
    SELECT AC.EMPLEADO,
            AD.ADMINISTRADORA,
            AD.DESCRIPCION,
            AD.TIPO_ADMINISTRADORA,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY AC.EMPLEADO, AD.TIPO_ADMINISTRADORA ORDER BY AC.FECHA_INGRESO DESC) RN
    FROM ADMINISTRADORA AD
    JOIN ADMIN_COTIZANTE AC ON AD.ADMINISTRADORA = AC.ADMINISTRADORA
)
SELECT EMPLEADO,
    MAX( CASE WHEN TIPO_ADMINISTRADORA = 'AFP'  THEN DESCRIPCION END),
    MAX( CASE WHEN TIPO_ADMINISTRADORA = 'ARP'  THEN DESCRIPCION END),
    MAX( CASE WHEN TIPO_ADMINISTRADORA = 'CCF'  THEN DESCRIPCION END),
    MAX( CASE WHEN TIPO_ADMINISTRADORA = 'EPS'  THEN DESCRIPCION END),
    MAX( CASE WHEN TIPO_ADMINISTRADORA = 'ICBF' THEN DESCRIPCION END),
    MAX( CASE WHEN TIPO_ADMINISTRADORA = 'SENA' THEN DESCRIPCION END)
FROM cteAdminCotizanteDetalle
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY EMPLEADO;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono tal cual lo necesitaba.